# Вывод данных из БД используя AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

Доброго времени суток. Скажу сразу, что новичок в AJAX. Перерыл весь интернет, но рабочего ничего не нашел.

Нужна помощь в выводе данных из БД, используя AJAX + PHP. 
В таблице несколько полей - `id`, `name`.
Расположены несколько `<button id="">`, на которые при нажатии должен выводиться соответствующий `name` для соответствующего `id`.

К примеру, есть 2 строки в таблице вида `id, name`:
`1, name1`, `2, name2`.  При нажатии на кнопку `<button id="1">` выводился `name1`.

Немного погуглив, собрал что-то вроде скрипта, который должен работать, но он не работает. Что здесь не так?

Получаю кнопки с id-ами:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <?php 
         if ($stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `table` ')) {
             while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
                 echo '<button type="button" id="';
                 echo $row['id'];
                 echo '">';
                 echo '</button>';
             }
         }
    ?>
</div>

<div id="info"> 
     <!-- Здесь должен быть вывод name при нажатии -->
</div>
```

Скрипт Ajax, который должен отвечать за вывод после нажатия на опред. кнопку:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#buttons').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "file.php",
                data: "buttons="+$("#buttons").val(),
                success: function(html){
                     $("#info").html(html);
                }
             });
             return false;
         });
     });
</script>
```

file.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        print $row['name'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного прочитав документацию, немного погуглив, пришел к единственному решению:

html:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <?php 
         if ($stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `table` ')) {
             while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
                   echo '<button type="button" id="';
                   echo $row['id'];
                   echo '" onClick="func(';
                   echo "'";
                   echo $row['id'];
                   echo "'";
                   echo '); return false;">';
                   echo '</button>';
              }
          }
     ?>
</div>

<div id="info"> 
     <!-- Здесь должен быть вывод name при нажатии -->
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
<script>
function func(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "show.php",
        data: { id : id },
        success: function(data) {
             $('#info').html('<div>'+data+'</div>'); 
        },
        error: function(request, status, errorT) {
             alert('error');
        }
    });
} 
</script>
```

show.php

```
<?php
     include_once 'modules/config.php';
     include_once 'modules/connect.php';

     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE id = ". $id;

     if ($stmt = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
            print $row['name'];
        }
     }
?>
```

Comment: Это ж как надо было гуглить, чтобы ничего не найти про json

Comment: @Ипатьев приведешь пример кода через json?